# My ViewModel does not survive configuration changes

Tags: java, android, mvvm, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying out Dagger 2 with MVVM. Here is what I have so far,

My ViewModel binding module:

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MedicationsViewModel.class)
    @Singleton
    abstract ViewModel bindMedicationsViewModel(MedicationsViewModel viewModel);

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory factory);
}
```

My Fragment:

```
class MedicationsFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    private lateinit var binding : FragmentMedicationsBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: MedicationsViewModel

    @Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory : ViewModelFactory

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentMedicationsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MedicationsViewModel::class.java)

        val adapter = MedicationAdapter()
        binding.rvMedications.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.getMedications().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { items ->
            if (items != null) {adapter.submitList(items); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()}
        })

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel is like this:

```
class MedicationsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MedicationRepository,
    ): ViewModel() {
        private var medications : MutableLiveData<MutableList<Medication>> = MutableLiveData()
        private val disposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

        fun getMedications() : MutableLiveData<MutableList<Medication>>{
            getMockMedications()
            return medications }

        private fun getMockMedications(){
            val medication1 = Medication(1,"Mock Med 1", "2018-01-01","once per day",true,null)
            val medication2 = Medication(2,"Mock Med 2", "2018-01-02","once per day",false,"before 15 minutes")

            val mockList: MutableList<Medication> = mutableListOf()
            mockList.add(medication1)
            mockList.add(medication2)

            medications.postValue(mockList)
        }

        fun addMedication(medication: Medication){
            medications.value?.add(medication)
            medications.notifyObserver()
        }

        fun <T> MutableLiveData<T>.notifyObserver() {
            this.postValue(this.value)
        }
    }
```

Through a button in my fragment, I am opening an activity and adding another Medication item to my viewmodel. After finish() out from my activity, I can see the newly added Medication item in my RecyclerView in fragment. However, when I rotate the screen I lost the newly added item and left with my mock Medication items again. This is where I think a new instance of my viewmodel is being created.

The problem might be a cause of Dagger creating a new instance of my viewmodel everytime my fragment (and container activity) is recreated. But I thought annotating my ViewModelFactory with @Singleton scope would have fixed it.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing at least 4 different things here.

---

> The problem might be a cause of Dagger creating a new instance of my viewmodel everytime my fragment (and container activity) is recreated.

You declare `viewModel` to be field injected when you inject your fragment (since you added an `@Inject` annotation on the property...)

```
@Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory : ViewModelFactory
```

This means that Dagger will inject the field when you call `AndroidInjection.inject(..)`. Since you use constructor injection (`@Inject` on the constructor of `MedicationsViewModel`) Dagger will create a *new* object (you didn't scope the class) every single time, but you're never using the object anyways because...

---

Right after *that* happened, you override the field with the viewModel from the `ViewModelFactory`

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MedicationsViewModel::class.java)
```

Since the ViewModelFactory uses the `@Binds @IntoMap @Singleton bindMedicationsViewModel` this *should* reuse the same object and be `@Singleton` scoped. You didn't share your implementation, so if it isn't the same object you might not properly handle your `@Singleton` component.

### More issues...

> But I thought annotating my ViewModelFactory with @Singleton scope would have fixed it.

Usually you should **put scopes on the class** and not on the binding.

```
@Singleton // scope the class!
class MedicationsViewModel @Inject constructor()
```

This is because it is usually an implementation detail what scope something has. But in any case, you **should not use `@Singleton` here at all, since you are trying to use the ViewModel thingy**. If you want to use `@Singleton` for your ViewModel then you don't need the whole `ViewModelProviders` bit. As you can see this will only lead to errors and confusion as both have different scopes and are handled differently.

### A better setup

Assuming you want to use ViewModels you do *not* scope the ViewModel with Dagger. You let the Android Arch components handle things. You only use Dagger to remove the boilerplate of the object creation so that `ViewModel.Factory` can easily create a new ViewModel *when necessary*. You do so by binding the ViewModel to the collection that gets passed to your factory (the map with `<Class, Provider<ViewModel>>`) Calling `provider.get()` will thus will always create a new object, as expected. The lifecycle gets handled by the arch components after all.

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(MedicationsViewModel.class) // no scope here!
abstract ViewModel bindMedicationsViewModel(MedicationsViewModel viewModel);

// neither here!
class MedicationsViewModel @Inject constructor()
```

With the setup in place ViewModelStoreOwner (`ViewModelProviders.of(this)`) will manage the ViewModels lifecycle and decide when to reuse or recreate the model. If you were to introduce a Dagger scope on the ViewModel it will either do nothing (if the scope is shorter lived) or might lead to bugs or unexpected behavior (when using `@Singleton` or longer lived ones)

Further the `ViewModel.Factory` should also be unscoped

```
@Binds // no scope here either!
abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory factory);
```

This is so that you can also add ViewModels on your Fragment / Activity scoped components and will enable you to inject classes that are not singleton scoped as well. This will greatly improve flexibility. A scope on the class wouldn't have any benefits either, since the ViewModels don't get stored in there during configuration changes and it doesn't hold any state.

Last but not least, you don't inject the field with Dagger, but you use `ViewModelProviders` to initialize it. While it shouldn't *do* anything, since you override it again moments later, it's still a bad smell and will only lead to confusion.

```
// in your fragment / acitvity
lateinit var viewModelFactory : ViewModelFactory // no @Inject for the viewmodel here!

// it will be assigned in onCreate!
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MedicationsViewModel::class.java)
```

I hope this clears some things up!

Comment: Thank you for your comprehevensive answer. I tried removing scopes as you suggested but problem was still there. So after a little debugging, I found out that my viewModel is actually the same one after lifecycle changes. The problem was due to a silly mistake of mine. In my viewmodel code, in this line `fun getMedications() : MutableLiveData<MutableList<Medication>>{
            getMockMedications()
            return medications }` I was actually creating a brand new list of mock data, whenever my observer calls for it. I got rid of it and the problem is solved.

Comment: Hi David in you answer for better setup, everything remained as is, only scooping is removed, and the the Inject field, how we are going to initialize factory if we remove the @Inject when creating a factory? app is crashing by doing so...

Comment: @ObaidJatoi This answer is quite dated by now. I recommend you take a look at Hilt which will simplify a lot of workflows with dagger on android

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, you may need to move your viewModel instantiation to `onActivityCreated` to ensure that the viewModelStore has been created.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelProviderFactory).get(MedicationsViewModel.class);
    ... 
    }
```